# CURL: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: php, curl

When trying to do the following command i'm getting this error:

```
curl -i -v -X POST -H Accept:*/* -H Cont
ent-Type:application/json -d "{user:{firstname:"Jane",lastname:"Smith"" -L "http
://site.com/test.php"
```

---

```
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* About to connect() to site.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 38.102.226.21...
* connected
* Connected to site.com (38.102.226.21) port 80 (#0)
> POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: site.com
> Accept:*/*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 36
>
* upload completely sent off: 36 out of 36 bytes
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host site.com left intact curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

test.php simply does: var_dump($_POST);

What can be the cause of it? The request is not reaching my index.php at all which receives all the traffic, so this can't have anything to do with my php code right?

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean the request isn't reaching test.php?

Comment: I'm sure because i'm not getting a reply at all.. I tried wiresharking the request and it just returns nothing, nada, not even a single bit. I tried logging when the request reaches my test.php and it's not working either. (and yes the log is working fine)

Comment: I presume test.php does work in browser? I'd start by making sure CURL headers are identical to browser ones (including User-Agent).

Comment: It is working fine on localhost yes, so i'm clueless

Comment: @CaptainObvious: 38.102.226.21 is not localhost...

Comment: I meant when i test the test.php on localhost with the exact same command i get a reply...

Comment: @CaptainObvious you better include some error logging on test.php
Also, it helps if you post test.php code here.

Comment: Like i said the request doesn't reach my test.php, it has something to do with the server i host on.. I tried to make the request in nodejs and it returns: "Error: socket hang up"